# Render table with Jade/Express.js having multiple elements per row

Tags: html, node.js, express, html-table, pug

I'm trying to render a table using jade from a simple array of objects. But instead of simply rendering one row per object, I want to render three objects on each row.

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>obj0</td>
      <td>obj1</td>
      <td>obj2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>obj3</td>
      <td>obj4</td>
      <td>obj5</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
objects = [[obj0, obj1, obj2], [obj3, obj4, obj5]]

table
  thead
  tbody
  for object in objects
    tr
      for subobject in object
        td= subobject
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of re-organizing the objects before the table building loop.

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer technically works, but I didn't like that you had to construct the data so that the logic works. I think that the logic should accomodate the data. As such, I came up with this:

```
objects = [obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]

table
  thead
  tbody
    - var columns = 3
    - for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i=i+columns)
      tr
        - for (var j = 0; j < columns && i+j < objects.length; j++)
          td=objects[i+j]
```

Comment: Looking back on this, you can achieve the best of both worlds between this answer and the accepted answer if you use something like [lodash's `chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk). You can use the more readable approach by just reordering your data dynamically (however, this is assuming your list is small; you'd pay a performance penalty for `chunk`ing very big lists)