# Create table in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

How to create table in html using express.js responce to browser in json formate,Using jquery click button.Any help related to this will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: What you have done show some code.

Comment: [***What have you tried so far?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/), converts JSON response from Ajax, and builds a table in HTML.

Example:

http://www.dynatable.com/#json-from-ajax

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check below url might help you.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180096/render-table-with-jade-express-js-having-multiple-elements-per-row
```

You can use Jquery datatable that takes Json as a input and shows a table in user interface. You can check the examples in below url. you just have to make the JSON structure compatible with jquery datatable format.

```
http://datatables.net/examples/
```

Comment: Add it as comment, its not an answer

Comment: Express.js response in json format and how to display that data in html table using jquery