# Displaying a JSON dataset as a table with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

First of all, I would like to point out that I'm very new to Node.JS. I'm trying to use NodeJS to make a page containing multiple tables and info. My problem is, that I can't get the result from the SQL query into an HTML table. Currently I `.send` the data into an HTML page using express.

Code that I use:

```
    var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {});
      var mysql = require("mysql"); 
      var express = require('express');
      var app = express();
      console.log('Creating the http server');
      con.query('SELECT id ,name FROM customer', function(err, rows, fields)
    {
        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
        console.log('num of records is '+rows.length);

        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
          res.send(rows);
        });

    });

    app.listen(3002, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    })
```

This prints all the data from my sql statement on my HTML page:

```
{"id":"1","name":"Robert"}
{"id":"2","name":"John"}
{"id":"3","name":"Jack"}
{"id":"4","name":"Will"}
```

what I would like to have as result is :

```
id              Name
1               Robert
2               John
3               Jack
4               Will
..etc
```

Is this even possible to do in Node JS?

Comment: I am trying to create an table. Sorry for the wrong suggestions.

Comment: So you're trying to display the resultset in a table in HTML? (Creating a table is, in database terms, a different thing)

Comment: I would like to create  an table into my HTML page  not in my database

Comment: There's multiple approaches to this, you could render it as a table serverside or you could fetch the JSON from the clientside, loop through it and make the table there, which one do you prefer?

Comment: I think the best way to do it for me is using JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you look at [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). It is a template engine for node js which can be used to create html pages. It is easy to use and very flexible.

A good tutorial is found [here](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus). It shows you how to create a simple Website with Node, Express and Jade and is a good starting Point in my opinion.

To solve your problem with Jade there are several answers in stackoverflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180096/render-table-with-jade-express-js-having-multiple-elements-per-row).

Comment: Thank you for the tip I did look at Jade an managed to get an template together but I still don't know how to get an table in my page. Where do I put the code for the table ? (layout or index)

Comment: If your question is refering to the tutorial I recommended, I would put the code in index (but it doesn't really matter). Later the tutorial explains in the app.get(...) part that res.render(...) is used to display your layout on the client side. The tutorial is really good, so just go step by step and make sure you have an idea about whats going on. Jade can be confusing at first but just play around a little and see what happens

Comment: Tutorial link is dead

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Jade you could use [Embedded JS](http://ejs.co/)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th><th>Name</th>
  </tr>

  <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= data[i].id %></td>
      <td><%= data[i].name %></td>
    </tr>    
  <% } %>
</table>
```

This would iterate through an array of objects (which I have saved as `data` and populate a table based on that.